# IL code generation for Object.Equals

Tags: c#, .net

Even though the type resolved to Int32 at runtime, the IL shows it called object.equals instead of int32.Equals, like this example:

```
object x = 5;
object y = 5;
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
```

But it returns True, that means it performed a value equality. I guess my question is shouldn't IL should have been `instance bool [mscorlib]System.Int32::Equals(int32)`

```
// [18 13 - 18 27]
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5     
IL_0002: box          [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0007: stloc.0      // x

// [19 13 - 19 27]
IL_0008: ldc.i4.5     
IL_0009: box          [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_000e: stloc.1      // y
// [21 13 - 21 46]
IL_000f: ldloc.0      // x
IL_0010: ldloc.1      // y
IL_0011: callvirt     instance bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object)
IL_0016: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
IL_001b: nop
```

Comment: "the type resolved to Int32 _at runtime_" - this the key point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `object.Equals` method is virtual, and is overridden in `Int32`. `callvirt` is a polymorphic call - it will check the run-time type of the object before calling a virtual method, and use the correct implementation.

`Int32` implements `IEquatable<T>` interface and defines another overload of `Equals`

```
public bool Equals(Int32 obj);
```

The compiler can choose this overload only if the compile-time types of both the parameter and the value it's called on is `Int32`. Here, the compile-time types are `object`, so the compiler can only use the `object.Equals(object obj)` overload.

Comment: And of course if both comparands are `int` at compile-time (declared types), the sane thing to do is to say `==` between those two integers. This goes to a C# predefined overload `bool operator ==(int, int)` which the compiler knows well, and which the compiler translates into a simple equality check on the two numbers on the stack. So you would rarely call `int.Equals(int)` directly.